# How to sort ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> which contain number and string

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

Hello i get json response in following format

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you can parse the size and then sort them.

For Example,

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List<String> sizes = new ArrayList<>();
        sizes.add("10X12");
        sizes.add("4X6");
        sizes.add("3X2");
        sizes.add("5X12");
        sizes.add("8X12");

        Collections.sort(sizes, new Comparator<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2)
            {
                int s1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.split("X")[0]);
                int s2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.split("X")[0]);
                return s1-s2;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(sizes);        
     }
}
```

Cheer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the actual `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`:

Of course, this is probably slower than first parsing the whole thing to get an ArrayList, and then sorting that more easily and efficiently, without doing a bit of parsing in every comparison.

But you explicitly asked for sorting an `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`, maybe out of curiosity, or because it actually is more practical in your case, so here you go :)

```
class Size
{
    int width;
    int height;
}

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)X(\\d+)");
final String papersizeKey = "papersize";

Size readSize(String description)
{
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(description);

    Size result = new Size();

    result.width = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    result.height = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));

    return result;
}

void sort(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> paperSizes)
{
    paperSizes.sort(new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>()
    {
        public int compare(HashMap<String, String> lhs, HashMap<String, String> rhs)
        {
            Size lhsSize = readSize(lhs.get(papersizeKey));
            Size rhsSize = readSize(rhs.get(papersizeKey));

            int result = Integer.compare(lhsSize.width,  rhsSize.width);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return Integer.compare(lhsSize.height,  rhsSize.height);
            }
        }
    });
}
```